# Chartist on Angular 4 broke my app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My application stopped, and I get the following error when I run the ng serve:

[photo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwd1n.png)

I'm using chartjs for some animations

this is the code in the charts.component.ts file

```js
   

        /* ----------==========    Rounded Line Chart initialization    ==========---------- */
**Error start here**

        var data = {
          series: [[
            { x: 1, y: 100 },
            { x: 2, y: 50 },
            { x: 3, y: 25 },
            { x: 4, y: 66 },
            { x: 5, y: 30 },
            { x: 6, y: 22 }
          ]]
        };

        var options = {
          axisX: {
            type: Chartist.AutoScaleAxis
          },
          axisY: {
            type: Chartist.AutoScaleAxis
          },
        //   plugins: [
        //     Chartist.plugins.zoom({
        //     onZoom : function(chart, reset) { this.storeReset(reset); },
        //     })
        // ]
        };

        var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);

        var dataRoundedLineChart = {
            labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
            series: [
                [12, 17, 7, 17, 23, 18, 38]
            ]
        };
```

Comment: at the docs they say `The data object that needs to consist of a labels and a series array` so...maybe you're missing the label option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` argument passed to this method:

```
var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);
```

is expected to implement the following interface:

```
interface IChartistData {
    labels?: Array<string> | Array<number> | Array<Date>;
    series: Array<IChartistSeriesData> | Array<number> |  Array<Array<number>>;
}
```

You're not doing this with your current `data` variable:

```
 var data = {
     series: [[
         { x: 1, y: 100 },
         { x: 2, y: 50 },
         { x: 3, y: 25 },
         { x: 4, y: 66 },
         { x: 5, y: 30 },
         { x: 6, y: 22 }
     ]]
};
```

You don't need to provide the x axis as part of this data. Chartist will infer this from the position of elements in the array. Try this:

```
var data = {
    series: [
      [
        100,
        50,
        25,
        66,
        30,
        22
      ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment unfortunately, I'll edit when my suggestion is confirmed,

From what I could saw with the exemples of chartist, 'data' is expecting an array of labels, which isnt here. Could you try adding one and see what it does ?

Comment: The `labels` property on `IChartistData` is marked as optional. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chartist/index.d.ts

Comment: True, Daniel May got the problem